# ignore folder when running eslint -fix

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to ignore the ./client folder when running this line on package.json

```
"lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
```

However, im unsure about how to do this when it comes to ignoring the `./client` folder

Comment: try add `--ignore-pattern '/clinet/'` option

Comment: ok will trry that